# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, cors

SERVERSIDE

```
// Set Headers
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, authorization, Verification");
        next();
    });

app.use('/user', authMiddleware.authenticateToken, userRoutes);
```

CLIENTSIDE

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
```

I have no idea why this happens. If i remove the authMiddleware, then everything works fine.

ANSWER:
I think the problem is that I used USE instead of a specific route. When I add the middleware to a route it works fine. I thought I can use USE to add middleware but that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check in browser's developer tools network tab. Are those headers present ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When browsers come across a cross-origin AJAX call, it has to determine if the endpoint understands CORS protocol and what are the acceptable domains/methods/headers are. To do so they will fire Preflight Request in OPTIONS method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

However not all AJAX call will trigger such preflight request. For example, if you just directly call

```js
fetch('https://google.com/some_api')
```

which is essentially to fire a GET call without parameters to https://google.com/some_api, browser might choose to skip preflight and just fire the actual GET call.

Answer (score -1):

You should allow OPTIONS method, too. The preflight of the request consists of a request with method OPTIONS, which you should reply to with full headers and empty body.
Also check if your middleware does not throw exception on authentication.

Comment: So, allowing options and add a preflight route or something?

Comment: @ARVOCI Cors works like this: when you try to perform a request that is not on the same origin the browser automatically sends an OPTIONS request to the same URL you are trying to retrieve, this OPTIONS request will tell the browser whether doing this cross origin request is okay, if so it proceeds with performing the actual request. This OPTIONS request is called the "preflight request". There is no preflight *route*.

Comment: @GACy20 i get that. When i add the middleware to specific route, it works. So i think the USE route is not supposed to support middleware to do that or something.